# Passing gathered value in API call from first method to second in same object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop, parameter-passing

I have a object which contains two methods. The first one is calling API and storing `response` in variable.

In second method I execute first one using `this.nameOfFirstMethod()` and then I want to do some calculation basing on numbers which I collected in API call in first method.

To make it more clear take a look at code, start reading at second method:

```
this.currencyConverter = {
    getRatio: function(selectedCurrency) {
        var selectedCurrency = selectedCurrency;
        $http({
            url: 'http://api.fixer.io/latest?base='+selectedCurrency+'&symbols=PLN,CHF,EUR,USD,GBP',
            method: 'GET'
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            var currentCurrency = {
                toPLN:  response.data.rates.PLN,
                toCHF:  response.data.rates.CHF,
                toEUR:  response.data.rates.EUR,
                toUSD:  response.data.rates.USD,
                toUSD:  response.data.rates.GBP
            };
            console.log("Succesful store currentCurrency");
            return currentCurrency;
        }, function(response) {
            console.log("Problem occure while downloading money current currency!");
            console.log(response.data);
        });
    },
    convertMoney: function(selectedCurrency,priceField) {
        var priceField = priceField;
        var selectedCurrency = selectedCurrency;

        console.log('selectedCurrency in service: '+selectedCurrency);
        console.log('priceField in service: '+priceField);

        this.getRatio(selectedCurrency);

        console.log(currentCurrency);

        /*
        var converted = {
            PLN: function() { return priceField * $rootScope.currentCurrency.toPLN; },
            USD: function() { return priceField * $rootScope.currentCurrency.toUSD; },
            EUR: function() { return priceField * $rootScope.currentCurrency.toEUR; },
            CHF: function() { return priceField * $rootScope.currentCurrency.toCHF; },
            GBP: function() { return priceField * $rootScope.currentCurrency.toGBP; }
        };
        */

    }
}
```

Here is GIST of same code if someone doesn't like StackOverflow styling:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e03de4de1af407bf70f4038acd77c961

Please open this gist because I will now explain basing on specific line.

So in the line 30 I execute first method.

In line 9 I'm storing retrieved data in variable and in line 17 returning this data (in order to use it in second method).

Finally I want to `console.log` this in second object in line 32 (for now only `console.log` I will do my maths later on).

It doesn't work with this `return`, the line with `console.log` in second method cause following error:

> ReferenceError: currentCurrency is not defined

Comment: The call to `this.getRatio(selectedCurrency)` is asyncronous, meaning that the code following won't wait for it to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't assign the return value of getRatio to a variable
it should be

```
currentCurrency = this.getRatio(selectedCurrency);
```

And you should work with promises correctly.
So change it to something like this (not tested)

```
this.currencyConverter = {
    getRatio: function(selectedCurrency) {
        var selectedCurrency = selectedCurrency;
        return $http({
            url: 'http://api.fixer.io/latest?base='+selectedCurrency+'&symbols=PLN,CHF,EUR,USD,GBP',
            method: 'GET'
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            var currentCurrency = {
                toPLN:  response.data.rates.PLN,
                toCHF:  response.data.rates.CHF,
                toEUR:  response.data.rates.EUR,
                toUSD:  response.data.rates.USD,
                toUSD:  response.data.rates.GBP
            };
            console.log("Succesful store currentCurrency");
            return currentCurrency;
        }, function(response) {
            console.log("Problem occure while downloading money current currency!");
            console.log(response.data);
        });
    },
    convertMoney: function(selectedCurrency,priceField) {
        var priceField = priceField;
        var selectedCurrency = selectedCurrency;

        console.log('selectedCurrency in service: '+selectedCurrency);
        console.log('priceField in service: '+priceField);

        var currentCurrency = this.getRatio(selectedCurrency);
        currentCurrency.then(res => console.log(res));

        //console.log(currentCurrency);           

    }
```

}

Comment: It changed my error to `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` let me add that this error in console appears before `console.log("Succesful store currentCurrency");` so it looks like `.then` isn't working correctly.

Comment: did you add the return $http in the first function?